# Would garou tribes be alright with a kinsfolk joining the Second Inquisition?

Tags: world-of-darkness, lore, werewolf-the-apocalypse, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

Is there anything within specifically 5e lore, that might suggest as to whether different Garou groups who have them, would be alright with homid kinsfolk leaving them to try join the Second Inquisition/FIRSTLIGHT?

With how they culturally dislike vampires and view them as "Wyrm Creatures", as well as how being part of the supernatural world means they might hear of the formation of the Inquisition, it seems like some might at least want to try - in absence of being able to take other active roles that Garou relatives can, in combatting the wyrm. But, there could also be reasons for the garou to not like the working with the human group.

Is there any official answer in 5e lore, that would indicate whether or not the tribes would actually allow or be okay, with in-the-know Kinsfolk doing this?

Comment: As a side note: at the curent state, there is no 5E Werewolf material that this could be based on. Since Vampire got a major theme and fluff overhaul, it is likely Werewolf will get a similar one.

Comment: no, I am saying that this question needs to be framed properly, possibly by restricting it to the 5E books out at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

If we limit ourself to the 5e, we only have vampire as a reference, so no, nothing stop a werewolf to join the inquisition (except the fact that if someone resist to their "aura of fear" (Can't remember the english term as I'm not an english speaker), he might have some silvered punch in the face).

If we use previous material, things are more complex. Some werewolf clans might join the inquisition (Glasswalkers for exemple, as they live in cities, and are the one that respect more the humanity), but they would not show that they are werewolfs, because, you know, silvered punch in the face... But not only. Werewolf have some kind of masquerade things too, even with their "aura of fear" (which shall not be use as an excuse to do stupid thing either).